# My tests never stop when using CMake and C++. How to test a program without starting its main function?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, infinite-loop, doctest

I recently started C++ with a little project of PuyoPuyo game (a kind of tetris) within the terminal. I'm using ncurses to play with the terminal and I have a loop that turns indefinitely when I launch my game. The binary is compiled with CMake and I use doctest for testing.

Here is what the current source code looks like: https://github.com/Th0rgal/poyuterm/tree/67a72af533e49aa9d164bc9227f4c56d18d6056e

My problem is that to test my program with unit tests, I need to be able to run only certain functions and create only certain objects, but when I try to run a test that only tests the Grid object for the shift functions from the Inputs class, in fact the test also seems to call the main function of the program and this is very annoying because it goes into the infinite loop, fills my terminal and it never stops.

Since I integrated the tests within CMakeList, I cannot longer build my program, it blocks on this instruction:

```
[  4%] Linking CXX executable test_inputs
```

If I remove the `doctest_discover_tests(` lines, I can now build the program and the different test binaries, but if I try to start them, they fulfill the terminal and never stop, however they should not call the main function. For example here are my tests for the Grid class:

```cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT
#include <doctest/doctest.h>
#include "domains/grid.hpp"
#include <iostream>

TEST_CASE("testing the constructor")
{
    vector<vector<Grid::PuyoType>> content =
        {
            {Grid::red, Grid::none, Grid::none},
            {Grid::none, Grid::red, Grid::red},
            {Grid::none, Grid::none, Grid::red}};

    Grid grid = Grid(content);
    CHECK(grid.content == content);

    content =
        {
            {Grid::none, Grid::blue},
            {Grid::red, Grid::yellow},
            {Grid::green, Grid::none}};

    grid = Grid(content);
    CHECK(grid.content == content);
}

TEST_CASE("testing the triggerGravity function")
{

    vector<vector<Grid::PuyoType>> content = {
        {Grid::red, Grid::none, Grid::none},
        {Grid::none, Grid::red, Grid::red},
        {Grid::none, Grid::none, Grid::red}};

    vector<vector<Grid::PuyoType>> expectedOutput =
        {
            {Grid::none, Grid::none, Grid::none},
            {Grid::red, Grid::none, Grid::red},
            {Grid::none, Grid::red, Grid::red}};

    Grid grid = Grid(content);

    CHECK(grid.triggerGravity() == false);

    for (int x = 0; x < grid.content.size(); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.content.size(); y++)
            CHECK(grid.content[x][y] == expectedOutput[x][y]);

    CHECK(grid.triggerGravity() == true);
}
```

Is it possible to test a C++ program without calling its main function? If so how to do it? And if not, how can I perform my tests?

Answer (score 0):

The `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
#...
set(SRCS
    src/main.cpp
    # all other .cpp files
    )
#...
add_executable(test_grid tests/grid.cpp ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
#...
```

`src/main.cpp` contains the `main()` function of your program, but that's probably not what should be executed in the tests, right?

Instead, you could omit `src/main.cpp` from `add_executable()` and ask `doctest` to provide its own `main()` with the `DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN` macro:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
#...
set(SRCS
    # all .cpp files except for src/main.cpp
    )
#...
add_executable(test_grid tests/grid.cpp ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
#...
```

`tests/grid.cpp`:

```cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include <doctest/doctest.h>

// ...
```